# Equality of electric charges of all leptons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

What does it precisely mean the often repeated statement that the electric charges of all leptons are the same.

Let's consider QED with two leptons: electron and muon. The interaction part of the bare lagrangian contains two electron-electron-photon and muon-muon-photon vertices with some coupling constants $e^{bare}_e$ and $e^{bare}_\mu$ respectively. After division of lagrangian into two parts: finite part and counterterms there are mentioned vertices in each part and the coupling constants in front of them are $e_e$, $e_\mu$ (finite/physical coupling constants), $\delta e_e$, $\delta e_\mu$ (become infinite when regularising parameter $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$; $\epsilon$ - deviation from dimension 4 in dimensional regularisation).

I suppose that the equality of charges of electron and muon means that 3-point vertex function $\Gamma^{(3)}$ at some fixed point $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ has the same value for electron-electron-photon and muon-muon-photon vertex (is there any distinguished point?). That should mean that (at least in some renormalization scheme) $e_e=e_\mu$. However, in general, for finite positive $\epsilon$, $\delta e_e \neq \delta e_\mu$ because the masses of leptons are different and we need different counterterms.

Comment: To be clear, you're not asking how this equality comes about, but rather how it is expressed in a QFT language?

Comment: Yes. I don't believe that at present it is possible to provide a convincing explanation of the existence of the universal elementary charge. I want to understand how the equality of electron and muon charge is expressed in (perturbative) QED.

Comment: OK, cool. I think for the leptons, though, the existence of the weak interaction forces this to happen, as in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98873/would-it-be-consistent-with-qed-to-have-leptons-of-different-charges).